# Combobox dynamic data display with itemsource option. How to select a particular item?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having a combobox and the data is assigned dynamically as follows

```
<combobox 
    name="clientbox"
    itemsource={Binding}, 
    displaymemberpath="ClientName" 
    selectedvaluepath="clientid" />
```

I am loading the client details from DB and setting them to a listbox and assigning to the combobox as follows.

```
clientbox.DataContext = <list>
```

I am able to see the data in the combox after run. This will select the 0th item, but I want to default select different item. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
  clientbox.SelectedItem =  ((ComboBoxItem)clientbox.Items[1]);
  clientbox.Text = ((ComboBoxItem)clientbox.Items[1]).Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

**Code-behind:**

```
// Setting the 0-based index
clientBox.SelectedIndex = 1;

// Setting the item
clientBox.SelectedItem = activeClient;

// Setting the value (explanation follows..)
clientBox.SelectedValue = activeClientValue
```

Using the `SelectedValue` property you can define a property of the item which is used to fill the `ComboBox`. An example: You fill the `ComboBox` with items of a class `Client` which has the properties `Id`, `Name` and so on. If you select an item, the `SelectedItem` property will be an instance of the class `Client`. By setting the `SelectedValuePath` property of the `ComboBox` to `Id` the `SelectedValue` will always just contain the id of the selected client.

**Binding:**

Of course you can always use bindings.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="clientBox"
    ItemsSource={Binding ClientList}, DisplayMemberPath = "Name" 
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    SelectedValue={Binding ActiveClient} />
```